# Overloading operator [ ] to use as a setter for Polynomial class

Tags: c++, polynomials

I have created a Polynomial class but I want to overload indexing operator to be used as a setter, for example, myPolyObject[0] = 2.5 but It's giving me an error when trying to overload it.

```
class Polynomial
{
public:
    Polynomial();
    Polynomial(Polynomial&);
    Polynomial(double* coefficient, int size);
    ~Polynomial() { delete [] polynomial ; }
    double operator [] (int exponent) const;
    friend ostream& operator << ( ostream& , const Polynomial&);
    Polynomial& operator = (const Polynomial&);
    double evaluate(double x) const;
    int getSize() const;
    double operator [] (int exponent, double coefficient);
    Polynomial& operator + ( Polynomial& );
    Polynomial& operator + ( double x );
    Polynomial& operator - (Polynomial&);
    Polynomial& operator - (double x);
    Polynomial& operator * (Polynomial&);
    Polynomial& operator * (double x);
private:
    double* polynomial;
};
```

In this code, I want double operator [] (int exponent, double coefficient) to take an index (exponent) for the array and set the value at that index to the double coefficient value.

Comment: `double& operator[](int exponent)`. You'd have to arrange for the operator to return a reference to a `double` value into which the coefficient could be stored.

Comment: But how would I set the exponent and value?

Comment: If you return a reference as Igor said, you simply get that one and set it to the value. Sounds confusing, so: rewrite it as `double& operator[] (int exponent);` and simply go like `polynomial[5] = 7.;` as you probably intended it to go like.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to want two different things, the first bit is answered in the comments, return a reference. Here is an example for completeness,

```
struct example
{
    double value_[10];
    double& operator [] (int index) {
       return value_[index];
    }
};

int main() {
    example e;
    e[0] = 2.2;
    std::cout << e.value_[0] << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/kkaFrt)

You then say..

> I want double operator [] (int exponent, double coefficient) to take an index (exponent) for the array and set the value at that index to the double coefficient value.

You can't have `operator[]` with multiple arguments. A couple of options are;
accept a `std::pair<int,double>`, which has pretty clean syntax. for example..

```
struct example
{
    double operator [] (const std::pair<int,double>& values) {
        return 2.0;
    }
};

int main() {
    example e;
    e[{1,2.2}];
    //or 
    e[std::make_pair(1,2.2)];
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/kkaFrt)

Or if you really want the comma, you could make your own type for the exponent and overload the comma operator.

```
struct exponent
{
    int exp_;
    double coeff_;
    exponent(int value) : exp_(value),coeff_(0){}

    operator std::pair<int,double>() {
        return std::make_pair(exp_,coeff_);
    }

    exponent& operator,(double coeff) {
        coeff_ = coeff;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct example
{
    double operator [] (const std::pair<int,double>& values) {
        return 2.0;
    }
};

int main() {
    example e;
    e[exponent(1), 3.3];
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/kkaFrt)

I'd personally go with something like the first option, or overload `operator()` instead.

Comment: "You can't have operator[] with multiple arguments" Can't you do this: `operator[](arg1, arg2)` Ugly as sin though and nitpicky.  Still, very good answer.

Comment: @doug No, you cannot define an overloaded `operator[]` taking two arguments in the first place. `operator[]` must be a member function taking exactly one argument.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry for the dumb comment. Great answer, btw.